# SQL SERVER 2012 table modify

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using VB2012 and SQL Server 2012. I exported a table from Access Database (2000 Format) to SQL Server 2012. But SQL Server is not allowing me to modify the table. I get a message that the table needs to be dropped and recreated. Is there a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the right permissions, you need to go to "Tools->Designers->Table and Database Designers" and uncheck the "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" option.

Comment: Tanx for your answer.